Determine whether the set $A=\{(0,0)\neq (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq |x|\}$ is connected.
This is an exercise from my Intro to Real Analysis class. The original questions asks to determine whether $A$ is closed, compact, and connected. I believe I was able to demonstrate closedness and compactness (the former by considering an open ball centered at $(0.5,0.5)$, and the latter by Heine–Borel). But I'm struggling to prove/disprove connectedness. I graphed the set in Desmos to help me visualize it.

I was able to show it's not path-connected. (Consider a path between $(-0.5,0)$ and $(0.5,0)$. Such a path would have to contain a point $(0,h)$ for some $h$, but no such point exists in $A$ since $(0,0)$ is excluded.) I know that if $A$ were open, path-disconnectedness would imply disconnectedness, however this is not the case.
I'm very new to the subject so I can't yet intuit whether a set is connected or not just from looking at it. My original instinct was that $A$ is disconnected, since on the graph there are two separate "regions" that don't "meet" anywhere (excuse my un-mathematical language), but neither of those regions are open so I can't directly apply the definition of disconnectedness.
A solution would be appreciated, a hint even more so!

What is your definition of connected set?

@Tri $A$ is disconnected if there exist open, disjoint sets $U,V$ such that $A\cap U\neq\emptyset$, $A\cap V\neq\emptyset$ and $A\subseteq U\cup V$. A is connected if no such $U,V$ exist.

The intuition here is that the set is not connected because the left and right parts of $A$ are two disjoint "pieces" of $A$. To make this idea rigorous, you want to write $A = B \cup C$ where $B$ and $C$ are disjoint relatively open sets, meaning they are disjoint and each is the intersection of an open subset of ${\mathbb R}^2$ with $A$. The natural choice for $B$ and $C$ would be the left and right portions of $A$, which can be written as
$$B = \{(x,y) \in A: x < 0\} = A \cap \{(x,y) \in {\mathbb R}^2: x < 0\}$$
$$C = \{(x,y) \in A: x  > 0\} = A \cap \{(x,y) \in {\mathbb R}^2: x > 0\}$$
This gives the desired decompostion $A = B \cup C$ and we conclude $A$ is not connected.
